# Detecting rendererID of GPU connected to main display in mac

Tags: macos, gpu

I am trying to detect the GPU that is used to render on the main display in mac OS. 
For doing this I find the `CGOpenGLDisplayMask` for the main display, using the following code.

```
CGDirectDisplayID mainDisplay = CGMainDisplayID();
CGOpenGLDisplayMask mainDisplayOpenglMask = 
        CGDisplayIDToOpenGLDisplayMask(mainDisplay);
```

Then I create a `CGLRendererInfoObj` and iterate over all the available renderers in `CGLRendererInfoObj` and query the display mask like this:

```
GLint displayMask;
CGLRendererInfoObj rendererInfo;
CGLDescribeRenderer(rendererInfo, index, kCGLRPDisplayMask, &displayMask);
```

My hunch was that the some displayMask value that I receive in `displayMask` should be equal to the `mainDisplayOpenglMask`, which I queried earlier. Since using `displayMask` I can query the connected monitors using `CGGetDisplaysWithOpenGLDisplayMask` which returns the correct results.

But I don't any value of `displayMask` which is equal to `mainDisplayOpenglMask`. Is there anything that I am missing in this or what I am doing is completely wrong?

If I am doing it completely wrong then is there a way to find the GPU connected to the main display without having to iterate over all the displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask is a bit field. A display's mask should only have a single bit set, representing that display. But the renderer's mask should have bits for all of the displays it can render to. So, don't check for equality, check if the display's mask bit is set in the renderer's mask:

```
if (displayMask & mainDisplayOpenglMask) ...
```

Comment: saved the day for me. Thanks! :)